# MQL5 Multi variables Array structure

Tags: mql5

How to create an Array on MQL5 that can hold 3 variablesand how to fill it and how to call it?
Please see the picture 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VspJb.jpg
[![array][1]][1]

**After nicholishen Answer when i try to Initialize array useing Variables i get the follwing error** : 'hi' - **constant expression required** 22.mq5  16  18

```
void OnStart()
{
   struct MyData { string name; double price; int volume; };
   // initializing an array of structs


     double hi= 0.01;


   MyData arr[] = {
      {"USDJPY", hi, 200},
      {"USDJPY", 110.100, 300},
      {"USDJPY", 110.200, 400},
   };

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when talking about 3 variables? different types of data (ints and doubles)? or something else?

Comment: No the same, I'm new  and learning and its driving me crazy

Comment: so what is the problem? you can have a two-dimensional array, second dimension must be fixed, first can be dynamic and change. e.g. `int array[][3];` then add more elements by using `ArrayResize` function - it is well documented so please show what you did and why it does not work so that we will try to help you wiht your code.

Comment: Daniel thank you for your replay, Just want to understand the array structure in MQL5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you are looking for is an array of structs. A struct is an object that can hold different types of data. Here is a example you can run in your terminal.

```
void OnStart()
{
   struct MyData { string name; double price; int volume; };
   // initializing an array of structs
   MyData arr[] = {
      {"USDJPY", 110.000, 200},
      {"USDJPY", 110.100, 300},
      {"USDJPY", 110.200, 400},
   };
   // changing some values 
   arr[1].name = "EURUSD";
   arr[1].price = 1.12;
   arr[1].volume = 1000;

   for (int i=0; i<ArraySize(arr); i++)
      printf(
         "Symbol=%s, price=%.3f, vol=%d", 
         arr[i].name, 
         arr[i].price, 
         arr[i].volume
      );
}
```

Comment: I got constant expression required when tryeing to Initialize array useing variables?

Comment: When initializing any array, regardless of type, you can only use constants not variables. Why do you tell me what you're trying to do and maybe I can show you a better way.

Comment: I want to save all open position information into array with unique identifying integer " ticket for example " so i can check the changes in position information